# How to get specific object key in array using MUI multiple autocomplete and useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to get id key in the given array list. When the user selected any object in a given array list need to get the id value to the state. How can I do it?

This is the sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tags-material-demo-forked-ffuvg4?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to set the ids to the state your can use map

```js
onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue.map((v) => v.id));
        }}
```